# Could an old person get arthritis in only one knuckle?

Tags: arthritis

Is Arthritis in one knuckle and no where else, possible for an elderly person ( 75 years or older)?  Or maybe the question should be is it likely ?

Answer (score 4):

[Monoarticular arthritis](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2003/0701/p83.html#afp20030701p83-t1), or inflammation of a single joint, is a not uncommon complaint. Common causes in an older patient include gout, pseudogout, trauma, and infection. Gonococcal arthritis is a particularly common cause when monoarticular arthritis is seen in a younger patient.